# Utilize DataTable sorting in subsequent tabs/visualizations

Tags: r, sorting, datatables, shiny

I am preparing a `shiny` app and am struggling with one particular behaviour. I would like the app to present a datatable (from the DT package) on the initial page with the inherent sorting functionality (specifically, the up/down arrows next to the variable names):

[image: datatable sorting]

However, I would then like to utilize the sorting information in subsequent tabs. The plot in the following script does update as expected, however if I go back to tab1 and redo the sort - the plot does not reverse the levels again and I'm not sure why. Having spent some time tinkering with this, I believe the issue is that the plot is not being triggered to be re-rendered when the sort is done (`input$data_rows_all` is not reactive?). Here is a MWE for the iris dataset:

```
state_ex <- function(data = NULL){
  library(shiny)
  library(shinydashboard)
  library(DT)

  ## UI #############################
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Save State Example"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Tab1", tabName = "tab1"),
        menuItem("Tab2", tabName = "tab2")
        )),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "tab1",
                h2("Tab1"),
                DT::dataTableOutput("data")),
        tabItem(tabName = "tab2",
                h2("Tab2"),
                plotOutput("plot"))
        )))

  ## SERVER #########################
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    dat <- reactive({
      df <- data
      return(df)
    })

    output$data <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(dat(), options = list(saveState = TRUE))
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      if (!is.null(input$data_rows_all)){
        sdat <- dat()
        means <- aggregate(input$data_rows_all ~ sdat$Species, 
                           FUN=mean)
        sdat$Species <- factor(sdat$Species,
                               levels = as.character(rev(means[,1])))
        plot(sdat$Species, sdat$Sepal.Length)
      } else plot(dat()$Species, dat()$Sepal.Length)
    })
  }

  runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
}

data(iris)
state_ex(iris)
```

I would like the plot in the second tab to be sorted by the `Species` column in the first tab (and have the sorting update if the user changes it).

I have set `saveState()` to true for the datatable, but I am not sure how to go about applying how it is sorted to the plot. Any advice would be very appreciated!

Comment: As an aside, I've looked at `str(dat()` (the reactive datatable object), and I do not see any information stored within the object that pertains to how it is be sorted and displayed in the app.

Answer (score 1):

`input$tbl_rows_all` gives you the indices of the sorted rows, where `tbl` is the name of the table object.
See a small example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plt"),
  dataTableOutput("tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$plt <- renderPlot({
    if(!is.null(input$tbl_rows_all)) plot(mtcars[input$tbl_rows_all, 1])
  })
  output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable({datatable(mtcars, options = list(stateSave = TRUE))})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not understand the significance of `input$tbl_rows_all` and that is awesome. This has gotten me very close to a working solution. I've entered my progress as an additional answer. As I describe in the solution, changing the sorting does update the plot (as desired), however if I go back to tab1 and reverse the sort again - the plot does not update. Any ideas?

Comment: (partial solution moved to the question)